# Redimensionar todos los elementos de una pagina web al cambiar tamaño de ventana

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi duda es como hacer para que todos los elementos de una página web se redimensionen conforme se cambie el tamaño de la ventana.

He probado con JQuery usando el siguiente código:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('*').width($(this).width()).height($(this).height());
});
```

Pero este código lo único que hace es coger el tamaño actual de la ventana y aplicarlo a todos los elementos, por lo que se ponen todos grandes :).

La idea es hacerlo como el zoom de los navegadores, cuando das a menos se hacen mas pequeños y viceversa...

Saludos.

PD:  No quiero hacerlo con CSS porque me tocaria cambiarselo a 1000 cosas...

Comment: **"PD: No quiero hacerlo con CSS porque me tocaria cambiarselo a 1000 cosas..."** - CSS es la manera correcta de hacer este tipo de cosas. Mejor anda preparándote

Comment: Pero hay alguna manera de hacerlo con JQuery?

Comment: Bueno, podrías usar JavaScript/jQuery para actualizar el CSS de todos tus componentes...

Comment: Usar Css es la forma mas limpia de hacer eso, con jQuery hay que contemplar muchas cosas, adicionalmente el performance va mucho mejor usando la hoja de estilos.

Comment: **"PD: No quiero hacerlo con CSS porque me tocaria cambiarselo a 1000 cosas..."** con Javascript te tomaría muchísimo más tiempo.
Debes usar CSS y vas a cambiar a 1000 cosas, hazlo fácil con Twitter Bootstrap o Zurb Foundation, un par de framework responsive cross-browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leyendo la pregunta no me queda muy claro si lo que quieres hacer es que el contenido cambie dependiendo de diferentes anchos de página o si por el contrario lo que quieres es que la página se visualice igual cuando la ventana cambia de tamaño (sin saltos, siempre de manera proporcional al ancho).

Si es lo primero, te recomendaría que fueses con un *framework* como Bootstrap como recomiendan en los comentarios. Si es lo segundo (como parece que lo es), aquí dejo dos posible soluciones:

### Opción 1: Usando `viewport`

Si el objetivo son dispositivos móviles, podrías utilizar [`viewport`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag) con un zoom y un ancho de página fijo. Así el contenido se vería igual en todos los dispositivos independientemente de su ancho (aunque seguramente habría diferencias en el alto):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

La propiedad `width` indica el tamaño del viewport y puede ser un valor numérico (sin unidades, en píxel) o un valor especial (p.e.: `device-width`); `initial-scale` indica el nivel de zoom inicial y luego puedes usar `minimum-scale` y `maximum-scale` para especificar el zoom mínimo y máximo respectivamente; y otra propiedad útil sería `user-scalable=no` que previene que el usuario pueda aplicar zoom y es útil en apps web para móvil.

---

### Opción 2: Usando `zoom` con CSS y JavaScript

Utiliza la propiedad [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom) de CSS con el elemento `body`, y actualízala dinámicamente con JavaScript cada vez que la ventana cambie de tamaño. El valor de `zoom` va de 0 a 1, por lo que el valor que le debes asignar sería = ancho de ventana / ancho deseado de contenido.

Sería algo como esto:

```js
// función que actualiza el zoom del elemento body
function actualizarTama() {
  
  $("body").css("zoom", window.innerWidth / 500);
  
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // actualizaremos el zoom cuando la ventana cambie de tamaño
  $(window).on("resize", actualizarTama);
  
  // y al cargar la página
  actualizarTama();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Título</h1>
<h2>Subtítulo</h2>
<p>Esta página está hecha para un ancho de 500 píxels, cuando la ventana cambia de tamaño, 
se aplica zoom para que todo se siga viendo de manera proporcional (como si la ventana 
siguiera teniendo 500px).</p>
<p>Pulsa en el botón "Página completa" y cambia el tamaño de la ventana, verás como el 
tamaño del contenido se mantiene siempre proporcional al ancho.</p>
<p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
```

---

Comment: Genial!!, El primer ejemplo que me has puesto es perfecto gracias. Pero e visto que usando la etiqueta meta viewport consigo el resultado deseado. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que viewport funcionara. Voy a cambiar la pregunta un poco para destacar esa opción.

Answer (score 4):

¿Por qué intentas ir por ese camino?, no sería más simple si implementas `bootstrap`, con el sistema Grid podrías lograr que los controles `html` se adapten de forma responsiva al cambio del browser.

[Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Creo que en un desarrollo moderno es la mejor opción para implementar desarrollos que se adapten a las diferentes dimensiones de las ventanas del browser.