# como hacer un div responsive?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo varios div como estos en mi pagina qe al hacer hover sobre un mapeado saldran a flote en dicha posicion que les otorge,pero tengo un problema y es que cuando cambia la resolucion la pagina es responsive pero los div no y se quedan los div del mismo tamaño y en la misma posicion y nose como hacer que se adapten al tamaño de la pagina y se agraden o encojan despendiendo la resolucion y que se posicionen nuevamente en el lugar correcto,ya que al achicarse o agrandarse el mapeo cambia ya que es responsive pero ellos no

```css
.bubble {
        background-color: #00CCCC;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
        background-image:         linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),
        3px 3px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
        color: #006699;
        display: block;
        font: 16px/25px sans-serif;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        }
      .bubble:after, .bubble:before {
        border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
        border-right: 25px solid #00CCCC;
        bottom: -25px;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: 25px;
        }
      .bubble:before {
          border-right: 25px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
          bottom: -28px;
          right: 22px;
          }
     @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
#Target{
  top: 5% ;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Target" class="bubble" style="top: 27%; left: 23.2%;" >Hola chicos</div>
<div id="Cliente" class="bubble" style="top: 35%; left: 10.4%;" >Que tal?</div>
    <div id="SegP" class="bubble" style="top: 48%; left: 4.4%;" >:(</div>
```

Comment: Echale un vistazo a bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ir haciendo todo más chico para resoluciones máximas. Empezando por `768px` que es la medida de las tablets y después puedes ir por `480px` que son los celulares.

En el siguiente [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyqaYV/) te dejo lo que has hecho pero con cambios para que tome los responsive, lo que hice fue achicar las medidas que tenías inicialmente y ponerle un `min-width` al contenedor para que no se rompa en caso de tener pocos caracteres, más que nada para `:(` que se veía mal.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bubble {
    padding: 5px 7px;
    min-width: 30px;
  }
  .bubble:after,
  .bubble:before {
    border-bottom-width: 12.5px;
    border-right-width: 12.5px;
    bottom: -12.5px;
    right: 12.5px;
  }
  .bubble:before {
    border-right-width: 12.5px;
    bottom: -14px;
    right: 11px;
  }
}
```

Para el posicionamiento de los `<div>` con respecto al responsive podés usar el [`window.addEventListener("resize", miFuncionResize)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) capturado el evento, calcular la nueva posición y cambiar las posiciones de los `<div>`.

Comment: Osea ir a chicandolas manualmente para cada resolucion que usare reduciendole los pixeles,pero otra cosa seria el posicionamiento de los div qe no los toma cuando cambia la resolucion como los puedo mover a los puestos en lo que deberan pasar en esa resolucion,llamandolos asi por id no me los toma

Comment: Para los posicionamientos vas a tener que usar javascript, calculando la nueva posición y cambiándola en el respectivo `div`.

Comment: si pero como haria para indicarle a js que haga ese posicionamiento cuando la pantalla cambie

Comment: Ya gracias a lo que me dijiste me abriste los ojos y lo encontre gracia,https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3202/82187 aqui dejare el link de la respuesta que me ayudo a redimensionar los elementos

Comment: Excelente! Hay diferentes formas, todo depende de como lo hagas y como querés que funcione.